# Java main() method doesn't run completely - Running a Client and Server from the same application

Tags: java, multithreading, client-server, program-entry-point, runnable

I have been working on the following code:

```
public class MyStuff {

    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
        //System.out.println("From Test"); 
        ControlGack gack = new ControlGack();
        gack.setVisible(true);
        MainWindow mW = new MainWindow();
        mW.run(null);

        Client c = new Client();
        try {
            c.run(null);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.print("Stupid");
    }
}
```

The `MainWindow` has a while loop that just repeats while the program is running.  How do I start the `Client` class and run it simultaneously with the rest of the program?

Comment: Run MainWindow on another thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few options...

1. Start the `MainWindow` in a separate `Thread`
2. Run the `Client` as a separate Java application

Using a new Thread should be a pretty easy fix - something like this...

```
Thread t = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        MainWindow mW = new MainWindow();
        mW.run(null);
    }
};
t.start();
```

Or, better yet, change your `MainWindow` class to `extends Thread` or `implements Runnable`. If you do that, you can simply execute it by calling `mW.start();` instead of your current `mW.run(null);` method,l and it will kick it off in a separate `Thread` for you.

Refer to the [Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) and [Runnable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) documentation for more information.

Answer (score 0):

While others have given you the exact answer you need, I might as well give you some link to start learning Thread in case you never use it before:

[Easy to understand: Thread](http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-threads-tutorial)

[Java Essential: Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/)

Good luck!